# doctrine credentials passed via Symfony2+nginx ENV vars aren't recognized; DB 'connection refused'. cmd line is ok. how to fix?

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

In a new symfony2 install, I launch Nginx via systemd with

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service 
    [Unit]
    Description=nginx
    After=syslog.target network.target

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/nginx
    ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
    ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
    PrivateTmp=true
```

where ENV vars are defined

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/nginx
    SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER="root"
    SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD="testtesttest"
```

used

```
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ...
    env SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER;
    env SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD;
    ...
    http {
        ...
```

and verified after restart

```
php -i | grep SYMFONY__DATABASE
    SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD => "testtesttest"
    SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER => "root"
    _SERVER["SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD"] => "testtesttest"
    _SERVER["SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER"] => "root"
```

According to "[How to Set external Parameters in the Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html)":

> Now that you have declared an environment variable, it will be present
>   in the PHP `$_SERVER` global variable. Symfony then automatically sets
>   all `$_SERVER` variables prefixed with `SYMFONY__` as parameters in the
>   service container.
>
> You can now reference these parameters wherever you need them.

So, changing credentials in

```
cat ./app/config/parameters.yml
    parameters:
        database_driver:   pdo_mysql
        database_host:     127.0.0.1
        database_port:     3306
        database_name:     "test_01"
        database_user:     "%database.user%"
        database_password: "%database.password%"
        mailer_transport:  smtp
        mailer_host:       ~
        mailer_user:       ~
        mailer_password:   ~
        locale:            en
        secret:            zzzz
```

with the default doctrine config

```
cat ./app/config/config.yml
    ...
    # Doctrine Configuration
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
    ...
```

should inherit the ENV-defined values

```
user <= "%database_user%" <= "%database.user%" <= SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER <= "root"
password <= "%database_password%" <= "%database.password%" <= SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD <= "testtesttest"
```

but, from site root, @ DB create with doctrine, connection is refused

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
    Could not create database for connection named `test_01`
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

From shell, there's no problem

```
mysqladmin -u root -p create test_01
Enter password: 
=> "testtesttest"

mysqladmin -u root -p 
    ...
    +------------------------------+
    |          Databases           |
    +------------------------------+
    ...
    | test_01                      |
    +------------------------------+
```

What needs to changed in the config above so that the doctrine execs correctly use the ENV-provided credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it's a known bug

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14426

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7555

workarounds, but no fix yet